# How can I delete history for specifc matching rows in Safari

Tags: safari

I want to delete specific site results from history of Safari.

Here I can see the results from `History` => `Show All History`:

[image]

When I select all rows (`cmd-a`) and apply delete it deletes one-by-one instead of all together. This also consumes extre memory.

Example screen view when I attempt to delete all rows, it just deletes them one by one:

[image]

Instead is there any way to delete all matching rows at once from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have an annoying habit of refreshing the page after every single change, but switching to another tab will speed up the process considerably.
It still does them one at a time, but doesn't have to bother with the redraw.

Comment: After switching to new tab can I close the ongoing one that deletes? Seems like it still deletes rows after it is closed

Comment: I didn't test for that. It would make sense.